# How to write Lua into TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex

I'm trying to figure out how put Lua output into TikZ. I know that Lua can be used to make tables but I don't understand why it doesn't work in this case.

In this example, I'm trying to generate a set of points with Lua and making a graph of them with TikZ. But I get a handful of errors when running this code. It may have to do with how I'm trying to do line breaks. Trying to write `%f, %f\n` yields the Omega symbol after each point.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization,math}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{luacode}
function data()
for x=0,10,1 do
tex.print(string.format("%f, %f\\\\",x,x+1))
end
end
\end{luacode}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\datavisualization[scientific axes]data[headline={x,y}]{\directlua{data()}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
%!TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization,math}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{luacode*}
    function data()
    tex.print([[\datavisualization[scientific axes]data[headline={x,y}]{]])
    tex.print("")--tikz seems to be really quirky on this
    for x=0,10 do
        tex.print(x..[[, ]]..(x+1))
        tex.print("")
    end
    tex.print([[};]])
    end
\end{luacode*}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \directlua{data()}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Done]